# Down sides of Async Task If Any

Tags: android, performance, android-asynctask

I know you are using it quite well with your Non-UI codes in AsnycTask but I am just wondering if there is any kind of problem while using AsyntTask? I am not having any code which produce the problem. But I am just curious to know Any bad experience if you have with AsnycTask and would like to share it.

Answer (score 3):

1. Memory Leak :

Even though activity is destroyed, AsyncTask holds the Activity's reference since it has to update UI with the callback methods.

2. cancelling AsyncTask :

cancelling AsyncTask using cancel() API will not make sure that task will stop immediately.

3. Data lose :

When screen orientation is done. Activity is destroyed and recreated, hence AsysncTask will hold invalid reference of activity and will trouble in updating UI.

Comment: You should use `WeakReference<Activity>` as a `Activity` reference and override `onCancelled()` in your `AsyncTask`, call   `AsyncTask.cancel(true)` inside `onDestroy()` of your `Activity` or `Fragment`, then clear the activity reference and nullify your `WeakReference<Activity>` object.

Answer (score 2):

- **Concurrent AsyncTasks:** Open `Asynctask.java` go to line number **199**, it shows you can create only 128 concurrent tasks
  `private static final BlockingQueue<Runnable> sPoolWorkQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(128);`
- **Rotation:** When `Activity` is restarted, your `AsyncTask`’s reference to the `Activity` is no longer valid, so `onPostExecute()` will have no effect.
- **Cancelling AsyncTasks:** If you `AsyncTask.cancel()` it does not cancel your `AsyncTask`. It’s up to you to check whether the AsyncTask has been canceled or not.
- **Lifecycle:** `AsyncTask` is not linked with `Activity` or `Fragment`, so you have to manage the cancellation of `AsyncTask`.

There are some workarounds to solve above issues for more details have a look at [The Hidden Pitfalls of AsyncTask](http://blog.danlew.net/2014/06/21/the-hidden-pitfalls-of-asynctask/)

Answer (score 1):

I just want to share the information that if you are using Asynctask, it will keep on doing its work even of the activity does not exist. 
So in case you have asynctask which starts in onCreate() of the activity, and you rotate the device. At each rotation, a new activity is created with a new instance of Asysntask. So many requests will be send over the network for same task.In this way, a lot of memory will be consumed which effects the app performance resulting in crashing it. So to deal with it Loaders(Asynctask Loaders) are used. 
For more info check the video:
[Loaders](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s4eAtMHU5gI&index=8&list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc9CBxr3BVjPTPoDPLdPIFCE)

Comment: It can be solved by cancelling your `Asynctask` at `onDestroy()`