# How to use thread and handler to hit Web API?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-handler

My Boss told me Not to use AsyncTask<> to hit a webservice. Standard told me use Threads to hit a webservice and then use the Handler to process the response from Thread. **Can someone ellobrate how to use thread and handler to hit a API and then give the control back to the Handler , atleast a Tutorial if its possible or Code. What is handler, is there only one Handler in android Application**?  thnks

Answer (score 0):

Please check it below example:

http://androidexample.com/Thread_With_Handlers_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=58

Answer (score 0):

What you are actually trying to do with `Thread` and update your GUI with `Handler` is same as using `AsyncTask`. `AsyncTask` considers most of the aspects which are somehow difficult to manage. Obviously there are some downsides to use AsyncTask for more details have a look at my answer [Down sides of AsyncTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40995049/down-sides-of-async-task-if-any/40997214#40997214)

**When to use?**

If you're supposed to perform a short time request, then `AsyncTask` is perfect. However, if you need to get some data and display it but you don't want to worry about whether to download again if the screen is rotated and so on, you should consider using an [AsyncTaskLoader](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncTaskLoader.html).

If you need to download some big data, then you can consider using an [IntentService](https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html).

Comment: Yeah i know that but you know boss is always right... :(